# UDF in Spark being called twice

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am running into a problem where my UDF is being called twice. The first SQL command I tried running is:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT city, CTOF(avgLow) AS Feren FROM citytemps ) AS x WHERE Feren > 30.0 ORDER BY Feren DESC").show();
```

where CTOF is my UDF.

I noticed that CTOF is being called twice here (I suspect in the WHERE clause and then again in the SELECT clause). I added print statements inside my CTOF function and saw that any ferenheit calculation that is above 30 degrees , CTOF is called twice. I'd rather it only be called once since I could have an extremely large dataframe.

After I didn't have much luck with that SQL command, I tried the following:

```
val ferenDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT city, CTOF(avgLow) AS Feren FROM citytemps");
ferenDF.registerTempTable("ferenTemp");
sqlContext.sql("SELECT city, Feren from ferenTemp WHERE Feren > 30.0 ORDER BY Feren DESC").show();
```

My UDF, CTOF, is still being called twice. Is there anyway I can run these SQL commands so that CTOF is only being called ONCE?
FYI, I am using Spark 2.1.0.

Comment: `ferenDF.cache().registerTempTable("ferenTemp");` could avoid atleast few recomputations due to `cache()`.

Comment: can you show the result of explain(true) on the dataframe?

Comment: @yunil.tang I ran the code and its working perfect. i.e. the udf is not called twice